# Monaco editor How to add custom language parser and syntax validation

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, monaco-editor

I am looking for documentation for defining custom language in Monaco editor.

I have searched for the document by didn't get any proper source.

I just want to define language similar to javascript like syntax where a user can define

functions, parameters (coming from json object), 
showing data suggestion coming from JSON.
keywords highlighting, syntax validation

Is there any documentation which can help me

Please suggest me help.

Comment: If you find an answer I will gladly take it too. I found it pretty easy to add autocompletion, syntax coloration, doc when hovering, but **syntax validation** seems to require that you write your own language service, and some doc on that would help

Comment: Same question here

Answer (score 0):

Defining your language in monaco is quiet easy, [here](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/monarch.html) is official documentation.
However Monaco can do validation on its own, only to:

- TypeScript,
- JavaScript,
- HTML,
- CSS.

To validate different languages you must write your plugin.